# Generating values from Normal Mixture distributions via copulas

Tags: r, normal-distribution, simulation, random-generation, copula

I have some values with unknown joint distribution, but I am assuming that the marginal distributions are two-part Normal Mixtures.
I am modelling the dependency between the distributions via vine-copulas and pairwise copula constructions.

What I want to do is simulate new values from these distributions, taking into consideration the dependency between them.

What I did:

- Estimated the parameters of the marginals using R (bayesmix)
- Used an empirical distribution function to get uniform values from the sample ones, so that I could construct the copula (I could also have used the estimated distributions for the transform)
- Constructed a vine copula and simulated values from it, meaning I now have uniform values for all variables (VineCopula package)

What I still need to do:

- Use the generated uniform values that possess the dependency information to get the actual values from the distribution. The problem here comes from the fact that I do not know the inverse CDF of the Normal Mixture and how to do this in R. If it was any of the standard distributions, for which I could calculate the inverse (or the inverse is already implemented), there would be no problem.

So my question is, how can I do this? Is there a way to do this?

I would prefer answers with both theory and R, but will be perfectly satisfied with either.

Comment: I do not know if this will work or not, you can have a try. You already know how to use inverse in R, via `qnorm`. So how about `$w_1$*qnorm()_1 + $w_2$*qnorm()_2`

Comment: I meant just multiply the weight by the inverse of each margins.

Comment: @Alice: this is not correct, the quantile function of the mixture is not the mixture of the quantile functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse cdf approach means solving (in $x^i$) an equation of the form $(i=1,2)$
$$\omega_1^i \Phi(\{x^i-\mu_1^i\}/\sigma_1^i)+(1-\omega_1^i) \Phi(\{x^i-\mu_2^i\}/\sigma_2^i) = u^i$$
Since this equation has no analytical solution, it need be solved by an numerical resolution. For instance, here is a raw R rendering of this resolution

```
f=function(x){.2*pnorm(.2*(x-1))+.8*pnorm(.7*(x+1))}
uniroot(f=function(x)f(x)-.3},
 interval=c(-1+qnorm(.3)/.7,1+qnorm(.3)/.2))
```

when $u^i=0.3$, with solution

```
$root
[1] -1.740754
$f.root
[1] -5.121608e-06
```

Note that both components do not need to be simulated this way. More precisely, $X^1$ can be generated from the corresponding Normal mixture, then transformed into $U^1$ by the mixture cdf, then $U^2$ can be generated from the copula conditional distribution, and $X^2$ derived by the above numerical inversion.

Comment: +1. It's no more difficult to provide a general solution for all Normal mixtures, as in `qmix <- Vectorize(function(q, mu, sigma, weights, ...) {
  f <- function(x) sum(weights * pnorm(x, mu, sigma)) - q;
  ifelse(0 < q & 1-q > 0, uniroot(f, range(qnorm(q, mu, sigma)), ...)$root, qnorm(q))
}, "q")`  As an example of its use (and a decent test) you can plot the quantile function, as in `curve(qmix(q, mu=c(1,-1), sigma=c(1/0.2,1/0.7), weights=c(0.2,0.8)), xname="q", ylab="x", n=1001)`.  Your example uses `q = 0.3`. This will work for inverting Gaussian KDEs, too.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for the generalisation and the comment about KDE inverse cdf generation, although I would not venture that path when generating them!